# How to return a single variable from a CUDA kernel function?

Tags: c, cuda

I have a CUDA search function which calculate one single variable. How can I return it back.

```
__global__ 
void G_SearchByNameID(node* Node, long nodeCount, long start,char* dest, long answer){
    answer = 2;
}

cudaMemcpy(h_answer, d_answer, sizeof(long), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
cudaFree(d_answer);
```

for both of these lines I get this error:
error: argument of type "long" is incompatible with parameter of type "const void *"

Answer (score 38):

I've been using `__device__` variables for this purpose, that way you don't have to bother with `cudaMalloc` and `cudaFree` and you don't have to pass a pointer as a kernel argument, which saves you a register in your kernel to boot.

```
__device__ long d_answer;

__global__ void G_SearchByNameID() {
  d_answer = 2;
}

int main() {
  SearchByNameID<<<1,1>>>();
  typeof(d_answer) answer;
  cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&answer, "d_answer", sizeof(answer), 0, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  printf("answer: %d\n", answer);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Erogol both the kernel and the host code know the type from the `__device__` declaration

Comment: For some reason, this only works for me (Toolkit 6.5) if I replace `"d_answer"` with `d_answer`, i.e. remove the quotations.  Other than that, this works well.

Comment: The value always comes back as zero for me.

Comment: Can a `__device__` variable be thread local? Global variables like that don't work for multithreaded applications.

Comment: @Serge I honestly have no idea, I never tried with a multi-threaded application

Comment: This approach is not "re-entrant", in the sense of not supporting launches of the same kernel from multiple streams.

Answer (score 25):

To get a single result you have to Memcpy it, ie:

```
#include <assert.h>

__global__ void g_singleAnswer(long* answer){ *answer = 2; }

int main(){

  long h_answer;
  long* d_answer;
  cudaMalloc(&d_answer, sizeof(long));
  g_singleAnswer<<<1,1>>>(d_answer);
  cudaMemcpy(&h_answer, d_answer, sizeof(long), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost); 
  cudaFree(d_answer);
  assert(h_answer == 2);
  return 0;
}
```

I guess the error come because you are passing a long value, instead of a pointer to a long value.

Comment: You don't _have_ to `memcpy()` - there are other options, such as @wich 's answer. -1 unless you argue that copying is the best / only realistic option.

Comment: Note that the other option *does* do a `memcpy` (it's in the name `cudaMemcpyFromSymbol`). This answer uses dynamic allocation which is preferable for multithreaded applications vs the other which uses a global variable.