# How to return string from __global__ function to main function in C CUDA

Tags: cuda

I want the CUDA thread to return the processed string but it's not working.
Here is a similar code, I am working in.

I have written this code based on this [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619296/how-to-return-a-single-variable-from-a-cuda-kernel-function).

```
__global__ void kernel(char *gpuText)
{
  gpuText= "hello";
}

int main(){
  char *gpuText;
  char *cpuText;

  cudaMalloc((void **)&gpuText, sizeof(char) * 10);
  kernel<<<1, 1>>>(gpuText);

  cudaMemcpy(&cpuText, gpuText, sizeof(char) * 10, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  cudaThreadSynchronize();
  
  printf("Copied Text : %s \n",cpuText);
  
  return 0;
}
```

It prints the output `Copied Text : (null)`

Comment: Copy assignment of a constant string  to a bare pointer won't work in any C like language. It wouldn't work in the host either.  That is why things like strncpy exist. Also take 5 minutes to read up on null termination in strings. If you don't understand how it works in normal C, you won't understand how it works in CUDA

Comment: thanks that really helped me. I didn't know I had to create my own `__device__` function. thank you for the feedback.